# send file to server with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to send files to the server using PhoneGap. here is my code below the following function parameter file to send. the problem that if I insert a fake url as localhost server it shows me server error code = 2, and if I insert a real url displays me file not found code = 1

```
function gotFile(file)
{
    navigator.notification.alert(file.fullPath);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.mimeType="image/jpg"; 
        options.fileKey="file";
        var params = {};
        params.IdPrestation = "3d660013-3028-46c3-adfa-d7141a712ed7";
        params.IdPhoto      = "3a660013-3028-46c3-adfa-d7141a712ed7";
        options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = true ;

      var ft = new FileTransfer();

               ft.upload(file.fullPath,encodeURI('http://Myserver.fr/Phototheque.asmx/SavePhoto'),function(r)
               {      
                   //navigator.notification.alert(r.response,function(){});
                    alert(r.response,function(){});
                    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
               },
               function(e)
               {
               //navigator.notification.alert('Serveur Erreur:' + e.code,function(){});
                    cause_erreur(e.code);
                    /*
                    alert('Serveur Erreur:' + e.code,function(){});
                    alert("upload error source " + e.source);
                    alert("upload error target " + e.target)
                    */
               },
               options
               );//ft.upload


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly know your bug. However,  your uploading code seems to be normal and the error may occur because of the file size or the network state.The same time, you can check in server whether request and response work as expected.